# What does it take from the airlines to be ETOPS certified?

Tags: commercial-aviation, airline-operations, regulations, etops

I have been told that the airlines to be certified for **ETOPS** apart from the aircraft certification, engineering wise it should have some conditions met in order to get the certification and to maintain it too.

Answer (score 2):

The requirements for ETOPS certification by the FAA are outlined in the following Advisory Circular:

> **ETOPS QUALIFICATIONS.** The unique nature of ETOPS necessitates an evaluation of
>   these operations to ensure that the certificate holder's proposed programs are effective. The FAA
>   will review the certificate holder's documentation and training programs to validate that they are
>   appropriate for ETOPS. To receive approval to conduct ETOPS the certificate holder must
>   satisfy the following conditions:
>
> **a. Airplane.** The specified airplane-engine combination listed in the certificate holder's
>   application must have been certificated to the airworthiness standards of transport category
>   airplanes and must be approved for ETOPS. Guidance for airplane ETOPS type design can be
>   found in AC 25.1535-1 and § 121.162.
>
> [...]
>
> **b. Flight Operations and Maintenance Requirements.** The certificate holder must show
>   compliance with the flight operations requirements discussed in paragraph 303 and the
>   maintenance requirements discussed in paragraph 301.
>
> **c. Training Requirements.** The certificate holder should show that it has trained its
>   personnel to achieve competency in ETOPS and must show compliance with the flight
>   operations and maintenance training requirements discussed in paragraphs 302 and 304.
>
> **d. Requirements For ETOPS Approval.** Before the FAA grants ETOPS operational
>   approval to an applicant for two-engine ETOPS, the certificate holder must be able to
>   demonstrate the ability to achieve and maintain the level of propulsion system reliability that is
>   required for the ETOPS-approved airplane-engine combination to be used (appendix P to
>   part 121, section I, paragraph (a)). The certificate holder must also demonstrate that it can
>   operate the particular airframe and other airplane systems at levels of reliability appropriate for
>   the intended operation. This can be achieved directly by a successful in-service operational
>   history or by successfully validating all the required ETOPS processes according to the
>   Accelerated ETOPS Application Method in Appendix 3 of this AC.
>
> **e. Accelerated ETOPS Application.** An applicant for an initial operating certificate who
>   is applying for ETOPS authority at entry into service under the Accelerated ETOPS Application
>   method must comply with the same requirements for certificate holders outlined in this AC. It
>   should be understood that validation of an applicant with no previous operational experience
>   should be more robust than would be necessary for a certificate holder with operational experience. As is the case for all Accelerated ETOPS approvals, the Director, Flight Standards
>   Service must be satisfied that the applicant can operate to the standards expected of an
>   experienced ETOPS operator from the first day of service.

<sup>(FAA [AC-120-42B](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/120-42B.pdf))</sup>

The referenced paragraphs 301 to 304 can be found in the same [document](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/120-42B.pdf) and provide detailed requirements for operations, maintenance and training.

The details may vary around the world, but other aviation authorities will have similar requirements for certification.